# Hiding NavBar on tap not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

I successfully implemented UIGestureRecognizer on my UIWebView like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                          action:@selector(handleTap)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [myUniqueWebView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

There is some mistake in the following piece of code, but logic is this: I want to tap on a view to hide the NavBar and if it's already hidden I want to use the same logic to show it. And it's not working:

```
-(void) handleTap {
    NSInteger didHideNavBar;
    didHideNavBar = 0;
    if ((didHideNavBar = 0)) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        didHideNavBar = 1;
        NSLog(@"tap1");
    } 
    if ((didHideNavBar = 1)) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"tap2");
    }
}
```

Xcode shows me the "tap2" message and nothing happens.

Comment: check to see if "`self.navigationController`" is ***not*** null

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Could you give me a hint on how it should look in code?

Comment: Just do a NSLog(@"my NavController %@", self.navigationController); somewhere in your code and check was is displayed. If the display is "myNavController (null)" then you do not have any navigation controller and so won't be able to show/hide a navigation bar

Comment: When you are comparing two values you should use == not =.In if ((didHideNavBar = 0)) use ==.And as suggested by Zeus, declare NSInteger didHideNavBar = 0; outside the handleTap.

Comment: You can create a customize navigation bar, take a look on this [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990963/how-to-show-navigation-bar-with-touch-near-top-of-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare `didHideNavBar` outside the `handleTap` method and add `return;` at the end of first `if` like this:

```
NSInteger didHideNavBar = 0;
-(void) handleTap {
    if ((didHideNavBar = 0)) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        didHideNavBar = 1;
        NSLog(@"tap1");
        return;
    } 
    if ((didHideNavBar = 1)) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        didHideNavBar = 0;
        NSLog(@"tap2");
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add return; at the end of first if?

Comment: This works, but now it works only **once**! If I hide the NavBar, then I show it again I can no longer show it or hide it anymore.

Comment: set `didHideNavBar = 0;` in the second `if` statement. You forgot to do it in your code

Answer (score 0):

see your code. u are setting didHideNavBar variable to 0, which then in if condition is being set to 1, you navigation bar will hide and then will show. and you will not be able to see this actin as it will done in very short time.

Comment: So how should I override this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

hi please  make your `didHideNavBar` static,
    because whenever **handleTap** method is called , it assign value zero to `didHideNavBar`.

so make this changes

```
static NSInteger didHideNavBar = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) handleTap {

    BOOL isHidden = (parentViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha == 0);
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = (isHidden) ? 1 : 0;
}
```